# Can't find controller method when deployed

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileExist(string fileName)
    {
        bool result = true;
        string path = Server.MapPath(TempPath) + fileName + ".xlsx"; //Path for the file
        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(TempPath));
        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
        {
            if (path == Files[i])
            {
                //The filename already exists
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return Json(new { returnvalue = result });
    }
```

My JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveButton', function () {
var fileName = $('#fileName').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Calculation/FileExist',
    data: { 'fileName': fileName },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (result) {
        if (!result.returnvalue) {
            $('#errorMessage').text("The filename already exists. Please choose another one (The files are automatically deleted every second day)");
            $('#downloadButton').css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    }
});
});
```

When I debug this in VS it works fine. But when I have Published and put it up on a server it wont work.

My error looks like this:

[image]

Why is this not working when published?

Comment: What's the controller class name? How are your `routes` configured?

Comment: try to give absolute url rather than relative and test again

Comment: try to give `url: '@Url.Action("FileExist","Calculation")',`

Comment: @haim770 Controllers name is Calculation

Comment: Try using @Url.Action to resolve controller path

Comment: @Url.Action wont work if js function is written in a separate js file.

Comment: @Jitendra With a workaround that can be done as well :)

Comment: @Url.Action didn't work. As JitendraPancholi said the js is written in a separate js file

Comment: @VivekParekh: Yes, That's Why I gave +1 for your comment.

Comment: How do I solve this when the js is in a separate file?

Comment: I think the problem is the relative position... can you share a working url

Comment: @VivekParekh Make an answer and I will mark it

Comment: @krillezzz I have given an answer for both scenarios :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that `Calculation` is your Controller Class, try to give the ajax request as following

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '@Url.Action("FileExist","Calculation")',,
data: { 'fileName': fileName },
dataType: 'JSON',
success: function (result) {
    if (!result.returnvalue) {
        $('#errorMessage').text("The filename already exists. Please choose another one (The files are automatically deleted every second day)");
            $('#downloadButton').css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    }
});
```

And if this event is written in a seperate `js` file then here is a code for that.

In your View make a js function as

```
function GetUrlToCheckIfFileExist(){
    return '@Url.Action("FileExist","Calculation")';
}
```

And in your `js` file use the following code

```
var getUrlToCheckIfFileExist = window.GetUrlToCheckIfFileExist();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: getUrlToCheckIfFileExist,
data: { 'fileName': fileName },
dataType: 'JSON',
success: function (result) {
    if (!result.returnvalue) {
        $('#errorMessage').text("The filename already exists. Please choose another one (The files are automatically deleted every second day)");
            $('#downloadButton').css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the url in view and set in a javascript variable and use it in your js file.

for cshtml file

```
<script>
 var urlpath = '@Url.Action("FileExist","Calculation")';
</script>
```

for js file

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveButton', function () {
var fileName = $('#fileName').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlpath,
    data: { 'fileName': fileName },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (result) {
        if (!result.returnvalue) {
            $('#errorMessage').text("The filename already exists. Please choose another one (The files are automatically deleted every second day)");
            $('#downloadButton').css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: @krillezzz: check it out and let me know.